# ARM Assembly Traverse String

Tags: assembly, arm

I just start to learn ARM assembly and trying to traverse in the string. I looked at some solutions in the stackoverflow and tried to implement these solutions but in some reason I always get "0x00000000" instead of character itself. (on r2)

```
        AREA Reset, CODE, READONLY
        ENTRY

 st     LDR r1, string

 ll     LDRB r2, [r1], #1
        MOV r3, r2
        B ll
        ALIGN
 string = "Hello World\0"
        END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `ADR r1, string` instead of `LDR r1, string`.   `ADR` puts the address of `string` into r1 -- it turns into `ADD r1, pc, #N` with an appropriate value of `N`.  The `LDR` is loading the first 4 bytes of the string `"Hell"` into r1 (0x6c6c6548, if you're little-endian), right?